Weighted linear regression -- how to interpret when weighting matrix is not diagonal
The classical case of weighted least squares problem$$(X^TWX)\hat{\beta} = X^T Wy$$ is solving a problem of minimizing $${\operatorname{arg\ min}}\, \sum_{i=1}^{n} w_i \left|y_i - \sum_{j=1}^{m} X_{ij}\beta_j\right|^2 =
  \underset{\boldsymbol\beta}{\operatorname{arg\ min}}\, \left\|W^\frac{1}{2}\left(\mathbf{y} - X\boldsymbol\beta\right)\right\|^2$$
Where $w_i$ is the weight we assign to each observation. $W = diag(w_i）$ matrix is a diagonal matrix of such weights.  The interpretation is clear.
My question is if $W$ is not a diagonal matrix, but with $W_{ij}$ entries. How do I interpret my regression in that case? Instead of each term in the objective function is the error on one observation, we have a lot of "cross terms" like $W_{ij} (y_i - \beta x_i) (y_j - \beta x_j)$ (in the case of single-variable regression). What do those terms mean, and how will it affect our regression coefficients comparing to diagonal case, when $W_{ij}$ are present? Any difference when $W_{ij}>0$  or $W_{ij}<0$?
Specifically in the context of Generalized Least Squares, we know that     $${\hat{\boldsymbol \beta}} = \left( \mathbf{X}^{\mathrm{T}} \mathbf{\Omega}^{-1} \mathbf{X} \right)^{-1} \mathbf{X}^{ \mathrm{T}}\mathbf{\Omega}^{-1}\mathbf{y}. $$
is a best linear unbiased estimator for $||y - X\beta||^2$, where $\Omega$ is the covariance matrix of the estimation error $\epsilon = y - X\beta$. In other words we want to set $W = \Omega^{-1}$
I want to understand why and how to interpret it. For example if the errors are positively correlated we want to make $W_{ij}<0$. What does the term $W_{ij} (y_i - \beta x_i) (y_j - \beta x_j)$ mean in that case, and how would it change the coefficient comparing to when $W$ is just diagonal?

Could you be a little more specific about what you mean by "interpret"? The answer differs depending on what aspects of the regression you are talking about.

@whuber I added a bit more context.  Mostly about the interpretation of the objective function cross terms and how it might affect the regression coefficients

@whuber I added a more tangible example so maybe that clarifies my question further
